# How to use "cast" to go from each row being a test to each row being a participant

Tags: r

I have a dataset of an experiment, where each line is a particular test. Each participant did multiple tests. Each participant is identified by a unique ID.in the participant column.

I want to recast my data so that each row is one participant, with the data in columns. I tried using cast from the `reshape` library, but my command is not working:

```
cast(myData, particiant ~ Age)
```

for example, to get rows of participants with their respective ages.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you melt `myData` first? `cast` requires a "molten" data.frame to operate. What is the error you received? If you include the first 15 or so lines of myData, people will be able to help you much more efficiently. Please use `dput(myData)` to include your data.frame.

Comment: Chase, thanks for the quick comments. My understanding was that if my data was by test, then it was already molten. Perhaps I misunderstood that.

I tried to post a few lines of the data. Unfortunately, it just looks like a garbled mess as there are so many columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of data, here is my best guess about your problem, and a solution assuming my guess is right.

```
# create dummy data
mydf = data.frame(participant = rep(1:3, each = 3),
         test   = rep(letters[1:3], times = 3),
         result = sample(100, 9, replace = T))
```

Here is how the data frame looks

```
    participant test result
1           1    a     20
2           1    b     17
3           1    c     63
4           2    a     60
5           2    b     67
6           2    c     16
7           3    a     49
8           3    b     64
9           3    c     75
```

Now, if you want each row to contain all test results for a participant, here is how you would `cast` it.

```
mydf2 = cast(data = mydf, participant ~ test, value = "result")
```

This gives us the data frame shown below

```
  participant  a  b  c
1           1 20 17 63
2           2 60 67 16
3           3 49 64 75
```

If you can `dput` your data frame, it would be easier to provide a more custom solution for your issue and diagnose the error. Hope this was useful